# Upgrading target sdk to 29 on React Native 0.59

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, sdk, react-native-firebase

My current android target sdk on React Native is 28, but Play Store is showing to update it to 29.
So I made the following changes in android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    ext {
       googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" //changed to 29.0.3
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28 //changed to 29
        targetSdkVersion = 28 // changed to 29
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
}
```

But now when I run npx react-native run-android I get the following error.

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0.
  Required by:
      project :app
      project :app > project :react-native-firebase
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0
```

I am using react-native-firebase v5

Comment: any update on this ? got the same problem here

Comment: you are using supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" change it to 29.0.0. If it is still showing error than add available version for 29

Comment: There is no support library 29. You need to migrate to androidX.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps :-

- Open `android/build.gradle` in your React Native project.
- Then increment the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` values
  to **`29`**.

> In `android/build.gradle`

```
   buildscript {
       ext {
           buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
           minSdkVersion = 16
           compileSdkVersion = 29
           targetSdkVersion = 29
       }
       // ...
   }

   allprojects {
    // ...
   }
```

- Then in Android Studio, Run "Sync Project with Gradle Files" (`File` > `Sync Project with Gradle Files`).

And you should be all set.